# How to update images stored in Firebase storage with react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, firebase-storage

I'm creating an e-commerce app with Next js and firebase. initially the user will post a listing/ item. this item post contains fields such as title, detail, price, createdAt, discount,..., and array of images[]. this array is first uploaded to firebase storage and the returned links are being stored in that array in Firestore.

```
const uploadFiles = async () => {
    setLoader(true);

    const uid = uuid();
    const promises = images.map((file) => {
      const storageRef = ref(
        machineStorage,
        `machineImages/${session?.user?.email}/${uid}/${file.name}`
      );
      return uploadBytes(storageRef, file.blob);
    });

    // upload all files
    const res = await Promise.all(promises);

    // get download URLs
    const links = await Promise.all(res.map((r) => getDownloadURL(r.ref)));
    console.log({ links });

    // Add Firestore document
    const colRef = collection(machineDB, "machinePosts");
    const docRef = await addDoc(colRef, {
      year: year,
      price: Number(price),
      lastPrice: Number(lastPrice),
      negotiable: negotiable,
      images: links,
      detail: detail,
      title: title,
      discount: discount,
      phone: phone,
      location: location,
      storageRef: uid,
      postedDate: serverTimestamp(),
    });
    router.replace("/machine");
    setLoader(false);
  };
```

and now i'm handling an update of the post. so what i'm doing for this is that i'm fetching the doc with the id and making the edit then if the user decides on the new value they update or if not they cancel.

```
async function page({ params: { machineid } }) {
  let machine = "";
  if (machine == "") {
    const docRef = doc(db, "machinePosts", machineid);
    await getDoc(docRef).then((res) => {
      machine = res.data();
    });
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <EditMachine machine={machine} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default page;
```

and in `EditMachine` component

```
function EditMachine({machine}) {
  const [changed, setChanged] = useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(machine == "" ? "" : machine.title);
  const [detail, setDetail] = useState(machine == "" ? "" : machine.detail);
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(machine == "" ? "" : machine.location);

  return (...);

}
```

but what i'm struggling with is how can i make an update to the images? b/c the images are being stored inside of firebase storage and the links are being stored inside firestore.

the structure of storage

```
  machineImages --> [userEmail] --> [uid] --> filename
```

`uid` is a folder that has array of images. and its reference is stored inside firestore as `storageRef`. and the `filename` is the actual image being stored.

and my firestore data structure is

```
  machinePost --> [docid] --> {

  images: [
    0: [imageLink],
    1: [imageLink],
    2: [imageLink],
    3: [imageLink],
  ],

  storageRef: [uid for the storage folder that's mentioned above]

  }
```

so based on this if the user deletes an image, add another images, sort the image how can i handle that?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have an extra array in the Firestore document with the images file names.

Based on this array you can easily detect, in your front-end, if the user has made some changes to  one or more images (addition, deletion, modification, array order change, etc...). If it the case you regenerate the downloadURLs for the files that need  it, you update the two arrays (array of file names and array of downloadURLs) and you update the Firestore document.

Comment: but how can i manage storage?

Comment: If I'm not mistaking you have the `userEmail`, the `uid` and the `filename`s. So you can add, rename (i.e. copy and delete) or delete the files accordingly.

Comment: can you show me how can i do that?

Comment: To delete a file look at this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/delete-files?hl=en#delete_a_file). So depending on the cases (some files are just deleted, some are deleted and replaced by new ones, etc.) just combine some file uploads and deletions. Nothing rocket science, just chaining/orchestrating these operations according to the changes in the filenames array.